# regex template for Ukrainian phone numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am reading 'Automate the boring stuff with python'. Right now, I'm stuck on chapter 7 (Regex part). There is a template for American phone numbers, which I want to implement for Ukrainian phone numbers.

Ukrainian numbers can appear in the different formats, such as : +380445371428, +38(044)5371428, +38(044)537 14 28, +38(044)537-14-28, +38(044) 537.14.28, 044.537.14.28, 0445371428, 044-537-1428, (044)537-1428, 044 537-1428, etc.

Following, is my implementation, but it's not quite correct.  What do I need?

- When I'm copying some website pages, from all of the info I have copied, I want to extract the Ukrainian number appearing in this (044-537-1428) format.

```
    phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (^\+38?)                           # area code(not necessarily)
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))                  # carrier code(usually starts with 0
    (\s|-|\.)?                         # separator
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))                  # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)                          # separator
    (\d{4})                            # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?     # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

template for American number (according to the book) looks like the following

```
    phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))? 
    (\s|-|\.)
    (\d{3})
    (\s|-|\.)
    (\d{4})
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: there is my another "idea" https://pastebin.com/NG1tpSD4

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, an option would be to incorporate alternation, based on the types of patterns that we might have, such as:

```
^(?:\+38)?(?:\(044\)[ .-]?[0-9]{3}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}|044[ .-]?[0-9]{3}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}|044[0-9]{7})$
```

Or even more restricted than that, if we'd be validating.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S1EppA/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'^(?:\+38)?(?:\(044\)[ .-]?[0-9]{3}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}|044[ .-]?[0-9]{3}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}|044[0-9]{7})$'
string = '''

+380445371428
+38(044)5371428
+38(044)537 14 28
+38(044)537-14-28
+38(044) 537.14.28
044.537.14.28
0445371428
044-537-1428
(044)537-1428
044 537-1428
+83(044)537 14 28
088 537-1428

'''

print(re.findall(regex, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

> ['+380445371428', '+38(044)5371428', '+38(044)537 14 28',
>   '+38(044)537-14-28', '+38(044) 537.14.28', '044.537.14.28',
>   '0445371428', '044-537-1428', '(044)537-1428', '044 537-1428']

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/S1EppA/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/S1EppA/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my regex for all Ukrainian numbers:

```
^\+?3?8?(0[\s\.-]\d{2}[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{2}[\s\.-]\d{2})$
```

This allows:

- +380 XX XXX XX XX or
- +380-XX-XXX-XX-XX

or same without "plus"

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with python but I think following regex would resolve your problem

```
((\+38)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s\.-]?(\d{7}|\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{2}[\s\.-]\d{2}|\d{3}-\d{4}))
```

you can check it working [here](https://regexr.com/4m9pj)

Comment: This one doesn't work, something like `3809372271` will be valid, which should not.